# Is procastinating lengthen the samsara?

Tags: karma, daily-life, five-hindrances, samsara, guidance

I know that good or bad karma lengthen the samsara. Similary, Is procastination / laziness lengthen the samsara ?

Comment: "procrastination" does not mean, "doing something without thinking about the end result" -- it means, "delaying an action", e.g. with the thought, "I will not do this now, maybe I will do it tomorrow instead".

Comment: I feel that this question make no sense. If anyone did something without aiming to be enlightned , that deed will lengthen the samsara for sure. I'm going to delete the question. :(

Comment: It's actually a valid question and the Buddha did discuss this.

Comment: The Sublime Buddha: "This Dhamma isn't for lazy people..."

Comment: See also [Q&A Delayed speech as right speech (delay of skillful deeds)](http://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=8243.msg13270#msg13270) and [Q&A Buddhism and Procrastination](http://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=8243.msg13271#msg13271)

Comment: Refer to the **Saṅkārauppada sutta** to overcome procastination.

Answer (score 1):

The Buddha made a distinction between slow and fast practice. Since you're asking about procrastination, let's look at what the Buddha said about slow practice. As you can see, this path is indeed painful:

> [AN4.162:2.1](https://suttacentral.net/an4.162/en/sujato#an4.162:2.1): And what’s the painful practice with slow insight? It’s when someone is ordinarily full of acute greed, hate, and delusion. They often feel the pain and sadness that greed, hate, and delusion bring.

However, a better approach is to choose a more pleasant path with less craving, more kindness and deeper insight:

> [AN4.162:5.1](https://suttacentral.net/an4.162/en/sujato#an4.162:5.1): And what’s the pleasant practice with slow insight? It’s when someone is not ordinarily full of acute greed, hate, and delusion. They rarely feel the pain and sadness that greed, hate, and delusion bring.

An even better approach is to choose a pleasant path that is quicker:

> [AN4.162:5.5](https://suttacentral.net/an4.162/en/sujato#an4.162:5.5): They have these five faculties strongly:  faith, energy, mindfulness, immersion, and wisdom. Because of this, they swiftly attain the conditions for ending the defilements in the present life. This is called the pleasant practice with swift insight.

But since you asked about procrastination, the third path, which is the best, would only be available for one who gave up procrastination.

Answer (score 1):

Not if procrastinating what ever is akusala. One can train also in focus of procastination of form, sound, smell, taste, touch and thoughts and it would quickly lead out of Samsara.

But if delaying the kusala, the training, then hopeless wandering on can be expected.

> One should make haste in doing good deeds; one should restrain one's mind from evil; for the mind of one who is slow in doing good tends to take delight in doing evil.
>
> Story to [Dhp 116](https://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.09.bpit_en.html#s-dhp-116)

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, what ever trade that binds in this circle, but to get rid of delay, right in the "here&now"]*